# how to have a title in range slider and update the value shown

Tags: javascript, rangeslider, ion-range-slider

i have defined like this:

```
  $(".js-range-slider").ionRangeSlider({
                            type: "single",
                            min: 1,
                            max: 40,
                            grid: true,
                             onChange: function (data) {
                              console.log("--------------------- " + data.from);
                               }
                          });
```

using ion.rangeslider i need to show in the value selected area the value multiplied by another value. by example, i need to multiply * 5 the value selected.
i need to update this when the selected value changes

http://prntscr.com/qav6rd

in the example, i need to show "6 persons by 5€: 30€"